# Cannot add custom manifest file to Delphi XE3 project

Tags: delphi, manifest

I have an application developed with Delphi XE3. Now I need to elevate its previlege to Administrator so that it can work properly.

So I do as follows:

1. Create manifest file, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
 <dependency>
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity
       type="win32"
       name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
       version="6.0.0.0"
       publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
       language="*"
       processorArchitecture="*"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
 </dependency>
 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
   <security>
     <requestedPrivileges>
       <requestedExecutionLevel
         level="requireAdministrator"
         uiAccess="false"/>
       </requestedPrivileges>
   </security>
 </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

2. In the project options -> Application -> Runtime Themes -> Use custom manifest, set it to the saved manifest file.
3. Rebuild the project.

However, after that, when I run the application. It does not show the elevate to adminsitrator messagebox. I try to open and browse its resources. There is a manifest file inside the resource, but it is not the one I set.

So, how to set custom manifest file for a project?

Comment: Make sure to set the "Target" choice at the top of that window to each target type and check the setting.  I've had to hand edit the dproj file to fix issues with bad target info being stuck.  I also use Project Magician from Uwe Raabe which is a huge help.

Comment: @MarkF, Thank you very much. I edit the dproj file manually and the problem is solved.